# SQL FOREIGN KEY USAGE ? what does it really do ? and when it was needed?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, database-design

ok im makeing a simple database for my example, there is users data and the user company's data .

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `UID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `ownername` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `userstatus` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `userregistertime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `userlastonline` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`) ,
  INDEX `username` (`username` ASC) )
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `CID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `UID` INT(25) NOT NULL ,
  `companyname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `companyaddress` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `companyemail` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companyphone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `companyimage` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companyyahoo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companytwitter` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companykaskus` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companyfacebook` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companytype` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `companystatus` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companytemplate` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `companyintroduction` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `partnership` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`) ,
  INDEX `ownername` (`UID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `companyname` (`companyname` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `ownernamecompany`
    FOREIGN KEY (`UID` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`UID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

1.why after i insert data to the users table ( uid is auto increment ) it doesnt update my company UID table ?

if you have php knowledge please see how im inserting it.

```
$RegisterInsert1 = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (
`username`, `password`, `ownername`, `userregistertime`, `userlastonline`) VALUES (
:username, :password, :ownername, :userregistertime, :userlastonline)");
$RegisterInsert1->execute($RegisterData1);
```

as you see, i get, UID = 1 ( auto ) then  username,pasword,ownername,etc inserted on user table. but somehow my company UID is not updated. it should be UID = 1 then the rest CID ( auto ) companyname null, etc null.

2.am i right defining a foreign key usage for?

3.please give me the best example of inserting users data + company data with the right usage from the right usage of foreign.

how im doing it right now

```
// INSERT USERS DB
$RegisterInsert1 = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (
`username`, `password`, `ownername`, `userregistertime`, `userlastonline`) VALUES (
:username, :password, :ownername, :userregistertime, :userlastonline)");
$RegisterInsert1->execute($RegisterData1);

// GET USERS GIVEN AUTO GENERATED UID
// QUESTION ? THIS one should be automated by foreign useage ?
$GetUid = $dbConnect->prepare("SELECT UID FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$GetUid->execute($RegisterData3);
$UserID = $GetUid->fetch();
$RegisterData2['UID'] = $UserID;

// INSERT COMPANY INFO + UID
$RegisterInsert2 = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO company (
`UID`,`companyphone`,`partnership`) VALUES (
:UID, :companyphone, :partnership)");
$RegisterInsert2->execute($RegisterData2);
```

Comment: U will get more appreciate ans .. if u write only that code which is related to question drct...

Comment: what im trying to do is updateing the UID.company from UID.users when im inserting data olny to users table. UID.users are auto incr, and it should be copyied to UID.company when its incr.

so i dont have to use // GET USERS GIVEN AUTO GENERATED UID

. hope you understand. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why after i insert data to the users
>   table ( uid is auto increment ) it
>   doesnt update my company UID table ?

SQL does not support multiple assignment, you need to do this procedurally. You need to use (at least) one `INSERT` statement per table.

1. `INSERT INTO` `users` which
   auto-generates the `UID` value(s);
2. Capture auto-generated value(s) for
   `UID`;
3. `INSERT INTO` users supplying the
   captured `UID` value(s).

FWIW SQL Server 2008 makes this easy with an `OUTPUT` keyword i.e. the auto-generated values can be captured (to a staging temp table) within the `INSERT` statement. In MS Access, you could create a `VIEW` with a `JOIN` between the two tables then `INSERT INTO` the `VIEW` and the auto-generate value would appear automatically in both tables (only worked for a two-table `VIEW`). I don't know if mySQL has similar features.

Comment: yup no INSERT CASCADE. just UPDATE CASCADE :| . ive just notice it .

Answer (score 3):

The foreign key in your schema definition is the UID column in the Company table. This refers to a single row in the Users table. You can ensure that an invalid UID is never inserted into the Company table by adding a foreign key constraint...

```
ALTER TABLE COMPANY ADD FOREIGN KEY COMPANY_USER_FK (UID) REFERENCES USER(UID);
```

and this will cause attempts to add a UID into the Company name that don't exist in the User table to fail. You can add extra features so that deleting a User from the User table deletes all the matching rows in the Company table, as follows...

```
ALTER TABLE COMPANY ...etc... REFERENCES USER(UID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

or you can prevent users from being deleted if rows for them exist in the company table by...

```
ALTER TABLE COMPANY ...etc... REFERENCES USER(UID) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Although it doesn't apply to your schema, you could also cascade changes to the UID in the Users table by...

```
ALTER TABLE COMPANY ...etc... REFERENCES USER(UID) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Note that all of this only works on MySQL if the storage engine is `INNODB;`

Comment: ALTER TABLE COMPANY ...etc... REFERENCES USER(UID) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
this one. why it doent update? my company table is still empty when im inserting the users data.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooo i see there is no INSERT CASCADE. akakakak . stupid me .